# How do I do I make my program do math

Tags: ruby, math

What do I need to write to make this math work?

```
10 = t

20 = e

30 = d

if t + e = 30

    puts "yes i am good at math"

    elsif t + d = 77

    puts "oh no"

else

    puts "i love myself anyway"

end
```

---

Thanks so much.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Try Ruby](http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/0), [the free tutorials at RubyMonk](https://rubymonk.com/), or [Ruby In Twenty Minutes](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/). Best of luck.

Comment: For reference next time, it is extremely encouraged to explain what is presently happening / wrong with the current code, and what is the desired behaviour (also how you've attempted to solve the problem, if applicable), as specifically as possible. Don't just use SO as a debug service.

Answer (score 2):

in ruby this would look like...

```
t = 10
e = 20
d = 30

if (t + e) == 30
    puts "yes i am good at math"
elsif (t + d) == 77
    puts "oh no"
else
    puts "i love myself anyway"
```

Comment: Thanks so much David. Seeing it in this way makes it very clear on what I need to do. You explain it great.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `=` write `==` in the `if` or `elsif` conditions. `=` assigns a value, `==` checks if values are equal.